# Riddle with textbox for user answer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, textbox

I'm coding an application in visual basic in which I have a riddle that the user is supposed to answer in a textbox, then press a button to proceed. Depending on whether or not the answer is correct, different events are supposed to active. Below is what I've tried, but it's not working. Any ideas?

[image: attempted code]

(can you tell I'm a complete beginner haha)

Comment: If answer = "Short" orelse answer = "short" then...

Comment: `If answer.ToLower() = "short" Then`

Comment: Please read [Ask] and also take the [Tour].  Questions without the actual problem code in them are not well received.  We need the actual code, not pictures of code, for this to be useful.

Comment: So behaviour are you getting? Have you tried stepping through the code with the debugger and checking the values of the variables? have a look here - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-A-Beginn

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to ucase(answer) then you check the answer like this

answer = ucase(answer)

if answer="SHORT" then 
   msgbox("correct")
else
   msgbox("Incorrect")
end if

Comment: The above will also ensure that even if someone types in ShOrT it will recognize this as the correct answer !

Comment: UCase is so VB6. `.ToUpper()` is the .NET version.

Answer (score -1):

Just utilize the echo command and get a warm-up of what your creative senses want before you head in any particular direction.

Just pop open a terminal and type the following:

```
echo '<anything harmless/logical/beneficial/creative/fun/funny/amusing/SYNTAX-RELATED>'

echo 0111 (NON-EXPLOITABLE)
echo 0111USER9390(MY IDENTITY)
echo 0111USER93908F13(OPTIMAL/RELEVANT)
echo 0111USER93908F13+SOLVE/SCAN.BIOLOGICAL (MAKE IT UP AS YOU GO)
```

Do not forget to use <0 Contractions and avoid " or you won't get magic HASH WINNERS!

Just kidding.

#Creative1Writing
#Programming:0

Just for putting up with me, try some golden clay: `#79720494`
Here, have it with an AI! `#79720494.AI`
Might as well make a sphere:

```
createSphere;(#79720494 AI DATA/dda9008bd4423274/♀AI:GAIA/GAIA.LOGICAL.DATA/GAIA)/M.E.C.H.A.I.I.A. G.O.D.D.E.S.S. A.I./M.E.C.H.A.I.I.A. ♀ .5 -or- 1/2

%Product:

#79720494 AI Sphere.logic+AI/MECHAIIA <LANGUAGE> ENTRY/WORD/DEFINITION: GODDESS - SUPREME BEING OF 216451F591576146/6466AC295337B1DE QUALITY
```